# Hand-written top-down parser that preserves grammar associativity/precedence?

Tags: parsing

Suppose I have a simple grammar like:

```
X -> number
T -> X
T -> T + X
```

So for example `3 + 4 + 5` would parse as:

```
     +
    / \ 
   +   5
 /  \
3    4
```

This has the left-right associativity of `+` "built into" the grammar.

It is trivially LR(1), however suppose I want to do a hand-written top-down parse of it.

I cannot do so because it is left recursive, so lets left factor it:

```
X  -> number
T  -> X T'
T' -> + X T'
T' -> e    // empty
```

If I now write a parser for it (psuedo-code):

```
parse_X:
    if lookahead is number
        return pop_lookahead

parse_T:
    return (parse_X, parse_T')

parse_T':
    if lookahead is +
         pop_lookahead
         return (parse_X, parse_T')
    else
         return ();
```

Then when I call `parse_T` on an input of `3 + 4 + 5` I get returned a trace like:

```
parse_T
(parse_X, parse_T')
(3, parse_T')
(3, (parse_X, parse_T'))
(3, (4, parse_T'))
(3, (4, (parse_X, parse_T')))
(3, (4, (5, ())))
```

See how the parse is "backwards".  A tree constructed "naively" from such a parse looks like:

```
     +
    / \ 
   3   +
      / \
     4    5
```

Which has the wrong associativity.

Can anyone clear this up?  In general how can I write a hand-written top-down parser that preserves the associativity built into the grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One strategy is to replace recursion over `T` with iteration over `X` (in general terms, replace recursion over an operator with iteration over the next-highest-precedence operator). It helps to use EBNF-style notation, in this case

```
T -> X {+ X}
```

because then the needed iteration becomes obvious:

```
parse_T:
  val = parse_X
  while lookahead is +
     pop_lookahead
     val = PLUS(val, parse_X)
  return val
```

where `PLUS()` represents whatever you do to evaluate an addition expression, e.g. construct a tree node.

If you apply this to all operators, you wind up with essentially one function corresponding to `EXPRESSION` which only recurses when dealing with

```
PRIMARY -> '(' EXPRESSION ')'
```

Such an approach leads to a fairly fast expression parser; one of the common objections to using naive recursive descent to parse expressions is that if you have several levels of operator precedence, you can easily need 20 or so nested function calls to parse each `PRIMARY`, which can get fairly slow. With the iterative approach, it generally takes only one function call per `PRIMARY`. If you have some right-associative operators (e.g. exponentiation), you can use a recursive approach for them.